# Autosubscribe to GetResponse on custom form

Tags: forms, api, getresponse

I have a custom form (not using getresponse form builder) and want to integrate GetResponse API to auto subscribe email leads.  I do not want to use any of the getresponse form or landing page builders.  Just want to integrate using API or something else.

What are the  steps or where would i find this information?

Answer (score 0):

I tried that once and failed. After that I contacted Getresponse and they told me it wasn't possible. So I had to use their form builder. This is a long time ago so maybe things have changed. Why not ask their support team? You never know. Anyway, after my failure I joined [Aweber](http://usa.weloveourhost.com/aweber.html) and succeeded in doing what you're trying now. So you can also step over to A Weber if you want.